# Xbox USB storage into HDD

Tags: xbox-360

my question is, if i configure my USB storage for xbox , it will work lile a HDD (So i can install games on it) or like a memory card for games saves? And if it works like a memory card, is there a way to make it work like a HDD without the xbox to be modded? Thank YOU ( xbox 360 slim btw)

Answer (score 3):

When you insert the USB drive into the 360's USB slot, you should be prompted to format it prior to use. After that it will work just like any other drive for the console, which means games and saves can be loaded onto it normally.

It should be noted that if you take it out and use it in another computer, you will have to reformat it and you will lose your data.

Comment: That last sentence is not entirely true. You can format the USB so that 8GB of a 32GB memory stick (for example) is formatted for Xbox, and the rest is for PC use. [See here for more info](http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive)

Comment: I was speaking generally, but you are also correct. +1, thanks for clarifying.